# Something is killing my script, can't figure out what is doing it in code and outputs STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Whenever I run my script that was working yesterday, now it is killed today. My app is written in Java and I want to use Google Maps so when the users click on, say, bookstore or doctor icon in the app, they are taken to the Google location in the city wherever they are in the world.

However, what happens is it stops and hides the activity. The app starts from a splash screen and goes to icons splash. When I touch an icon, it gives the coordinates but doesn't output anything. I have changed the key and everything. Any ideas why?

**LogCat**

```
10-29 02:59:06.260  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide E/GeoData:﹕ Current Location
    Longitude: -81.06201496
    Latitude: 37.39213943
10-29 02:59:06.310  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide D/ActivityThread﹕ >>> handling: PAUSE_ACTIVITY
10-29 02:59:06.330  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide D/ActivityThread﹕ <<< done: PAUSE_ACTIVITY
10-29 02:59:06.380  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide D/ActivityThread﹕ >>> handling: LAUNCH_ACTIVITY
10-29 02:59:06.440  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide W/Query in activity :﹕ book_store
10-29 02:59:06.450  13409-13706/com.xtreme.cityguide W/URL is﹕ https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.39213943,-81.06201496&rankby=distance&types=book_store&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyC6zHflVgVCLKEMWBFMFm5qj0Jis-eoR4U
10-29 02:59:06.450  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide D/ActivityThread﹕ <<< done: LAUNCH_ACTIVITY
10-29 02:59:06.620  13409-13706/com.xtreme.cityguide I/System.out﹕ Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10-29 02:59:06.620  13409-13706/com.xtreme.cityguide I/System.out﹕ get login cookies:
10-29 02:59:06.620  13409-13706/com.xtreme.cityguide W/status line﹕ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10-29 02:59:06.630  13409-13706/com.xtreme.cityguide W/Size of City :﹕ 0
10-29 02:59:07.000  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide D/ActivityThread﹕ >>> handling: STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE
10-29 02:59:07.000  13409-13409/com.xtreme.cityguide D/ActivityThread﹕ <<< done: STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own... it was that I did not gps enabled